# Reading a Xml file from within a class

Tags: c#, winforms

Not sure how to right the title. Been doing a simple program that requires o user to login to an account. Made a separate class to store the user info and decided to make the reading and writing functions inside the class to make the code cleaner but when I try to read the user info it doesn't work.`

```
` public class LoginInfo
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }

        public LoginInfo()
        {
            this.username = "";
            this.password = "";
        }
        public LoginInfo(string username, string password)
        {
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "user:" + this.username + "\nPass:" + this.password;
        }

        public static void Load(LoginInfo[] arr)
        {
            string file = @"LoginInfo.xml";
            XmlSerializer fSrl = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LoginInfo[]));
            FileStream fStr = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
            arr = (LoginInfo[])fSrl.Deserialize(fStr);
            fStr.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("information loaded");
        }

        public static void Save(LoginInfo[] arr)
        {
            string file = @"LoginInfo.xml";

            XmlSerializer fSrl = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LoginInfo[]));
            FileStream fStr = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create);
            fSrl.Serialize(fStr, arr);
            fStr.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("information saved");
        }
    }`
```

The only fix i found was putting the code used to read on the other class that is attached to the form i'm using. Sry if the mistake is really obvious. Just been away from my confort zone when i try stuff like this.

Comment: Can you tell us exactly _how_ 'it doesn't work'?

Comment: Adding reading and writing functions inside the class will not make the code cleaner.
[Read more about it here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/single-responsibility-in-solid-design-principle)